# pgfplots 3D bar chart - wrong plotting order

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart, matlab2tikz

I am using `bar3` to plot 3d diagrams in Matlab but it seems that in LaTeX the plotting order is wrong ? Is there any way to have the right order?

[image] 
This is a small example of the generated 2.tikz file

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
unbounded coords=jump,
view={-37.5}{30},
scale only axis,
xmin=0.6,
xmax=1.4,
xtick={\empty},
xmajorgrids,
y dir=reverse,
ymin=0,
ymax=10,
ytick={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9},
ymajorgrids,
zmin=0,
zmax=1.8,
zmajorgrids,
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
axis z line*=left
]

\addplot3[%
surf,
shader=faceted,
draw=black,
colormap/jet,
point meta=explicit,
mesh/rows=4]
table[row sep=crcr,header=false,meta index=3] {
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
0.6 0.6 0 1\\
0.6 1.4 0 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
0.6 1.6 0 1\\
0.6 2.4 0 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
0.6 2.6 0 1\\
0.6 3.4 0 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
0.6 3.6 0 1\\
0.6 4.4 0 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
0.6 4.6 0 1\\
0.6 5.4 0 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
0.6 5.6 0 1\\
0.6 6.4 0 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
0.6 6.6 0 1\\
0.6 7.4 0 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
0.6 7.6 0 1\\
0.6 8.4 0 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
0.6 8.6 0 1\\
0.6 9.4 0 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
0.6 0.6 0 1\\
0.6 0.6 0.453486380396396 1\\
0.6 1.4 0.453486380396396 1\\
0.6 1.4 0 1\\
0.6 0.6 0 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
0.6 1.6 0 1\\
0.6 1.6 0.500551426394066 1\\
0.6 2.4 0.500551426394066 1\\
0.6 2.4 0 1\\
0.6 1.6 0 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
0.6 2.6 0 1\\
0.6 2.6 0.530653947397964 1\\
0.6 3.4 0.530653947397964 1\\
0.6 3.4 0 1\\
0.6 2.6 0 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
0.6 3.6 0 1\\
0.6 3.6 0.687568213750107 1\\
0.6 4.4 0.687568213750107 1\\
0.6 4.4 0 1\\
0.6 3.6 0 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
0.6 4.6 0 1\\
0.6 4.6 0.820537888833387 1\\
0.6 5.4 0.820537888833387 1\\
0.6 5.4 0 1\\
0.6 4.6 0 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
0.6 5.6 0 1\\
0.6 5.6 1.07871476415846 1\\
0.6 6.4 1.07871476415846 1\\
0.6 6.4 0 1\\
0.6 5.6 0 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
0.6 6.6 0 1\\
0.6 6.6 1.44792272826121 1\\
0.6 7.4 1.44792272826121 1\\
0.6 7.4 0 1\\
0.6 6.6 0 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
0.6 7.6 0 1\\
0.6 7.6 1.52540976235072 1\\
0.6 8.4 1.52540976235072 1\\
0.6 8.4 0 1\\
0.6 7.6 0 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
0.6 8.6 0 1\\
0.6 8.6 1.60554036231844 1\\
0.6 9.4 1.60554036231844 1\\
0.6 9.4 0 1\\
0.6 8.6 0 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
1.4 0.6 0 1\\
1.4 0.6 0.453486380396396 1\\
1.4 1.4 0.453486380396396 1\\
1.4 1.4 0 1\\
1.4 0.6 0 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
1.4 1.6 0 1\\
1.4 1.6 0.500551426394066 1\\
1.4 2.4 0.500551426394066 1\\
1.4 2.4 0 1\\
1.4 1.6 0 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
1.4 2.6 0 1\\
1.4 2.6 0.530653947397964 1\\
1.4 3.4 0.530653947397964 1\\
1.4 3.4 0 1\\
1.4 2.6 0 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
1.4 3.6 0 1\\
1.4 3.6 0.687568213750107 1\\
1.4 4.4 0.687568213750107 1\\
1.4 4.4 0 1\\
1.4 3.6 0 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
1.4 4.6 0 1\\
1.4 4.6 0.820537888833387 1\\
1.4 5.4 0.820537888833387 1\\
1.4 5.4 0 1\\
1.4 4.6 0 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
1.4 5.6 0 1\\
1.4 5.6 1.07871476415846 1\\
1.4 6.4 1.07871476415846 1\\
1.4 6.4 0 1\\
1.4 5.6 0 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
1.4 6.6 0 1\\
1.4 6.6 1.44792272826121 1\\
1.4 7.4 1.44792272826121 1\\
1.4 7.4 0 1\\
1.4 6.6 0 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
1.4 7.6 0 1\\
1.4 7.6 1.52540976235072 1\\
1.4 8.4 1.52540976235072 1\\
1.4 8.4 0 1\\
1.4 7.6 0 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
1.4 8.6 0 1\\
1.4 8.6 1.60554036231844 1\\
1.4 9.4 1.60554036231844 1\\
1.4 9.4 0 1\\
1.4 8.6 0 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
1.4 0.6 0 1\\
1.4 1.4 0 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
1.4 1.6 0 1\\
1.4 2.4 0 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
1.4 2.6 0 1\\
1.4 3.4 0 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
1.4 3.6 0 1\\
1.4 4.4 0 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
1.4 4.6 0 1\\
1.4 5.4 0 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
1.4 5.6 0 1\\
1.4 6.4 0 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
1.4 6.6 0 1\\
1.4 7.4 0 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
1.4 7.6 0 1\\
1.4 8.4 0 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
1.4 8.6 0 1\\
1.4 9.4 0 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
NaN NaN NaN 1\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

This is the Matlab code to plot the 3d bar

```
a1=[0.01 0.05 0.1 0.5 1 5 100 500 1000] ;
L1= reshape(a1,[3,3]) ;
b1=[1e-3 1e-3 1e-3 1e-3 1e-3 1e-3 1e-3 1e-3 1e-3] ;
L2= reshape(b1,[3,3]) ;
c1=[0.4535 0.5006 0.5307 0.6876 0.825 1.0787 1.4479 1.5254 1.6055] ;
r1= reshape(c1,[3,3]) ;
bar3(c1) ;
set(gca(gcf), 'xticklabel',{'1e-2', '5e-2' ,'1e-1', '5e-1', '1' ,'5' ,'100', '500' ,'1000'},'yticklabel',{'1e-3', '1e-3' ,'1e-3', '1e-3', '1e-3', '1e-3' ,'1e-3' ,'1e-3' ,'1e-3'});
xlabel('lambda1') ; ylabel ('lambda2'); zlabel('rmse abundance') ;
```

This is my LaTeX code

```latex
\begin{figure}[ht] 
\centering
\centering 
\setlength\figureheight{3cm}
\setlength\figurewidth{3cm}
\pgfplotsset{ tick label style={color=white}}
\input{bilder/2.tikz} 
\caption{versuch} \label{fig:versuch}
\end{figure}
```

This is the plot result with all data [image]

Comment: Can you make a small example from the contents of `2.tikz` file? Please don't just paste it. Take your time to make sure that the problem persists even with a smaller even manually typed data. And apart from the problem at hand do you really need bar plot for this? 3D bar plots are very bad at displaying data as you can directly see here.

Comment: thank you for your help . I have added the code in the question

Comment: The code you posted you posted is incomplete. A suggestion: make a plot in Matlab that uses only a few of the data points, but enough of them that the problem is evident. Then add the *complete* contents of the `.tikz` file generated by `matlab2tikz` to your question.

Comment: Could you post a working mini example (please include the tikzpicture part). At least, I can't compile your code, ie I get the error message `Package pgfplots Error: the arguments of [mesh/rows=4,mesh/cols=3] assume 12 ete or overcomplete!? [Use mesh/check=false to disable this message]. \end{axis}` and fixing the number of rows produces a different resulte than both of you picutres.

Comment: You could also try http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-exportfig

Comment: The tikz file is too long and I couldn't include it in the question because of the space problem . Is there any other method to add .tikz files here ?

Comment: Try just to add an mini example, with less data and columns that still produces the same error

Comment: By the way, maybe it's a better approach just to export the matlab data as an `csv`-file and than import the `csv-file` in tikz (looks much clearer) and than to flow the pgf documentation.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion . I'll try it . I've just reduced the data and it still produces the same error . The new tikz file is in the question

Comment: try to delete `mesh/rows=4` and try `mesh/ordering=x varies]` (default or maybe y varies)

Comment: I experimented with your example and I came to the conclusion that this is either a wrong matrix encoding (i.e. `mesh/rows` wrong or `mesh/ordering` wrong) or some bug in `pgfplots` (my expectation was that `z buffer=sort`, maybe even with the expensive `patch refines=2` would solve any ordering issues). Could you also post the `matlab` code to reproduce the (small) figure?

Comment: Yes I have posted the matlab code in the question. In fact I try to plot r1 as a function of L1 and L2.

Comment: If it's a problem with `matlab2tikz` you could also try to get some help on theit gethub page (https://github.com/matlab2tikz/matlab2tikz/issues). But make sure to use the latest version of `matlab2tikz`.

Answer (score 1):

I used the last version of `matlab2tikz` (v1.0.0.) and the results matched the matlab plot. Are you using the latest version of the package?
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \newlength\figureheight 
    \newlength\figurewidth 
    \setlength\figureheight{6cm} 
    \setlength\figurewidth{6cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[%
    width=0.527\figurewidth,
    height=\figureheight,
    at={(0\figurewidth,0\figureheight)},
    scale only axis,
    plot box ratio=1 12.5 7.725,
    point meta min=1,
    point meta max=2,
    unbounded coords=jump,
    xmin=0.6,
    xmax=1.4,
    xtick={\empty},
    tick align=outside,
    xlabel={lambda1},
    xmajorgrids,
    y dir=reverse,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=10,
    ytick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
    yticklabels={{1e-3},{1e-3},{1e-3},{1e-3},{1e-3},{1e-3},{1e-3},{1e-3},{1e-3}},
    ylabel={lambda2},
    ymajorgrids,
    zmin=0,
    zmax=2,
    zlabel={rmse abundance},
    zmajorgrids,
    view={-37.5}{30},
    axis background/.style={fill=white},
    axis x line*=bottom,
    axis y line*=left,
    axis z line*=left
    ]

    \addplot3[%
    surf,
    shader=flat corner,draw=white!15!black,z buffer=sort,colormap={mymap}{[1pt] rgb(0pt)=(0.2081,0.1663,0.5292); rgb(1pt)=(0.211624,0.189781,0.577676); rgb(2pt)=(0.212252,0.213771,0.626971); rgb(3pt)=(0.2081,0.2386,0.677086); rgb(4pt)=(0.195905,0.264457,0.7279); rgb(5pt)=(0.170729,0.291938,0.779248); rgb(6pt)=(0.125271,0.324243,0.830271); rgb(7pt)=(0.0591333,0.359833,0.868333); rgb(8pt)=(0.0116952,0.38751,0.881957); rgb(9pt)=(0.00595714,0.408614,0.882843); rgb(10pt)=(0.0165143,0.4266,0.878633); rgb(11pt)=(0.0328524,0.443043,0.871957); rgb(12pt)=(0.0498143,0.458571,0.864057); rgb(13pt)=(0.0629333,0.47369,0.855438); rgb(14pt)=(0.0722667,0.488667,0.8467); rgb(15pt)=(0.0779429,0.503986,0.838371); rgb(16pt)=(0.0793476,0.520024,0.831181); rgb(17pt)=(0.0749429,0.537543,0.826271); rgb(18pt)=(0.0640571,0.556986,0.823957); rgb(19pt)=(0.0487714,0.577224,0.822829); rgb(20pt)=(0.0343429,0.596581,0.819852); rgb(21pt)=(0.0265,0.6137,0.8135); rgb(22pt)=(0.0238905,0.628662,0.803762); rgb(23pt)=(0.0230905,0.641786,0.791267); rgb(24pt)=(0.0227714,0.653486,0.776757); rgb(25pt)=(0.0266619,0.664195,0.760719); rgb(26pt)=(0.0383714,0.674271,0.743552); rgb(27pt)=(0.0589714,0.683757,0.725386); rgb(28pt)=(0.0843,0.692833,0.706167); rgb(29pt)=(0.113295,0.7015,0.685857); rgb(30pt)=(0.145271,0.709757,0.664629); rgb(31pt)=(0.180133,0.717657,0.642433); rgb(32pt)=(0.217829,0.725043,0.619262); rgb(33pt)=(0.258643,0.731714,0.595429); rgb(34pt)=(0.302171,0.737605,0.571186); rgb(35pt)=(0.348167,0.742433,0.547267); rgb(36pt)=(0.395257,0.7459,0.524443); rgb(37pt)=(0.44201,0.748081,0.503314); rgb(38pt)=(0.487124,0.749062,0.483976); rgb(39pt)=(0.530029,0.749114,0.466114); rgb(40pt)=(0.570857,0.748519,0.44939); rgb(41pt)=(0.609852,0.747314,0.433686); rgb(42pt)=(0.6473,0.7456,0.4188); rgb(43pt)=(0.683419,0.743476,0.404433); rgb(44pt)=(0.71841,0.741133,0.390476); rgb(45pt)=(0.752486,0.7384,0.376814); rgb(46pt)=(0.785843,0.735567,0.363271); rgb(47pt)=(0.818505,0.732733,0.34979); rgb(48pt)=(0.850657,0.7299,0.336029); rgb(49pt)=(0.882433,0.727433,0.3217); rgb(50pt)=(0.913933,0.725786,0.306276); rgb(51pt)=(0.944957,0.726114,0.288643); rgb(52pt)=(0.973895,0.731395,0.266648); rgb(53pt)=(0.993771,0.745457,0.240348); rgb(54pt)=(0.999043,0.765314,0.216414); rgb(55pt)=(0.995533,0.786057,0.196652); rgb(56pt)=(0.988,0.8066,0.179367); rgb(57pt)=(0.978857,0.827143,0.163314); rgb(58pt)=(0.9697,0.848138,0.147452); rgb(59pt)=(0.962586,0.870514,0.1309); rgb(60pt)=(0.958871,0.8949,0.113243); rgb(61pt)=(0.959824,0.921833,0.0948381); rgb(62pt)=(0.9661,0.951443,0.0755333); rgb(63pt)=(0.9763,0.9831,0.0538)},mesh/rows=4]
    table[row sep=crcr, point meta=\thisrow{c}] {%
        %
        x   y   z   c\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        0.6 0.6 0   1\\
        0.6 1.4 0   1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        0.6 1.6 0   1\\
        0.6 2.4 0   1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        0.6 2.6 0   1\\
        0.6 3.4 0   1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        0.6 3.6 0   1\\
        0.6 4.4 0   1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        0.6 4.6 0   1\\
        0.6 5.4 0   1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        0.6 5.6 0   1\\
        0.6 6.4 0   1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        0.6 6.6 0   1\\
        0.6 7.4 0   1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        0.6 7.6 0   1\\
        0.6 8.4 0   1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        0.6 8.6 0   1\\
        0.6 9.4 0   1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        0.6 0.6 0   1\\
        0.6 0.6 0.4535  1\\
        0.6 1.4 0.4535  1\\
        0.6 1.4 0   1\\
        0.6 0.6 0   1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        0.6 1.6 0   1\\
        0.6 1.6 0.5006  1\\
        0.6 2.4 0.5006  1\\
        0.6 2.4 0   1\\
        0.6 1.6 0   1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        0.6 2.6 0   1\\
        0.6 2.6 0.5307  1\\
        0.6 3.4 0.5307  1\\
        0.6 3.4 0   1\\
        0.6 2.6 0   1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        0.6 3.6 0   1\\
        0.6 3.6 0.6876  1\\
        0.6 4.4 0.6876  1\\
        0.6 4.4 0   1\\
        0.6 3.6 0   1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        0.6 4.6 0   1\\
        0.6 4.6 0.825   1\\
        0.6 5.4 0.825   1\\
        0.6 5.4 0   1\\
        0.6 4.6 0   1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        0.6 5.6 0   1\\
        0.6 5.6 1.0787  1\\
        0.6 6.4 1.0787  1\\
        0.6 6.4 0   1\\
        0.6 5.6 0   1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        0.6 6.6 0   1\\
        0.6 6.6 1.4479  1\\
        0.6 7.4 1.4479  1\\
        0.6 7.4 0   1\\
        0.6 6.6 0   1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        0.6 7.6 0   1\\
        0.6 7.6 1.5254  1\\
        0.6 8.4 1.5254  1\\
        0.6 8.4 0   1\\
        0.6 7.6 0   1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        0.6 8.6 0   1\\
        0.6 8.6 1.6055  1\\
        0.6 9.4 1.6055  1\\
        0.6 9.4 0   1\\
        0.6 8.6 0   1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        1.4 0.6 0   1\\
        1.4 0.6 0.4535  1\\
        1.4 1.4 0.4535  1\\
        1.4 1.4 0   1\\
        1.4 0.6 0   1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        1.4 1.6 0   1\\
        1.4 1.6 0.5006  1\\
        1.4 2.4 0.5006  1\\
        1.4 2.4 0   1\\
        1.4 1.6 0   1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        1.4 2.6 0   1\\
        1.4 2.6 0.5307  1\\
        1.4 3.4 0.5307  1\\
        1.4 3.4 0   1\\
        1.4 2.6 0   1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        1.4 3.6 0   1\\
        1.4 3.6 0.6876  1\\
        1.4 4.4 0.6876  1\\
        1.4 4.4 0   1\\
        1.4 3.6 0   1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        1.4 4.6 0   1\\
        1.4 4.6 0.825   1\\
        1.4 5.4 0.825   1\\
        1.4 5.4 0   1\\
        1.4 4.6 0   1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        1.4 5.6 0   1\\
        1.4 5.6 1.0787  1\\
        1.4 6.4 1.0787  1\\
        1.4 6.4 0   1\\
        1.4 5.6 0   1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        1.4 6.6 0   1\\
        1.4 6.6 1.4479  1\\
        1.4 7.4 1.4479  1\\
        1.4 7.4 0   1\\
        1.4 6.6 0   1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        1.4 7.6 0   1\\
        1.4 7.6 1.5254  1\\
        1.4 8.4 1.5254  1\\
        1.4 8.4 0   1\\
        1.4 7.6 0   1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        1.4 8.6 0   1\\
        1.4 8.6 1.6055  1\\
        1.4 9.4 1.6055  1\\
        1.4 9.4 0   1\\
        1.4 8.6 0   1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        1.4 0.6 0   1\\
        1.4 1.4 0   1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        1.4 1.6 0   1\\
        1.4 2.4 0   1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        1.4 2.6 0   1\\
        1.4 3.4 0   1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        1.4 3.6 0   1\\
        1.4 4.4 0   1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        1.4 4.6 0   1\\
        1.4 5.4 0   1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        1.4 5.6 0   1\\
        1.4 6.4 0   1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        1.4 6.6 0   1\\
        1.4 7.4 0   1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        1.4 7.6 0   1\\
        1.4 8.4 0   1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        1.4 8.6 0   1\\
        1.4 9.4 0   1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
        nan nan nan 1\\
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{A plot of a sphere}
    \label{fig:sphere}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Have a look at:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
...
plot box ratio=1 12.5 7.725,
unbounded coords=jump,
        ]

        \addplot3[%
        surf,
        shader=flat 
        corner,draw=white!15!black,
        z buffer=sort,
        colormap/jet,
        mesh/rows=4]
        table[row sep=crcr, point meta=\thisrow{c}] {%
            %
            x   y   z   c\\
...
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer . Yes I am using the last version . With the small example it works and I became good results in Latex . But when I try to plot the hole picture the tikz plot and the matlab plot don't match .

Comment: I will add the latex plot in the question . Thank you for the help

Comment: I think the problem was the plotting order . He tries to plot the first values and he does it correctly then he plots the second values on the first and the third on the second etc . Is there any function that we can use to avoid changing the plotting order ? thanks